# Finding the remainder of a large number without the use of a calculator.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How would I calculate the following without using a calculator:
$152615278636986567767^{12345678}$ % $5$

I have gotten only the last digit by doing:
$152615278636986567767$ % $10 = 7$

Therefore having $7^{12345678}$ % $5$.

I am unsure of how I should do the rest to find the final remainder.

I had a look at similar formats like [How would I find the modulo of a large number without using a calculator that supports large numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728057/how-would-i-find-the-modulo-of-a-large-number-without-using-a-calculator-that-su), but I haven't learned any of the following rules/theorems.

Comment: I'd be curious how you think you could do this *with* a calculator!

Comment: You haven't learned about "Little Fermat" yet? Then, for this question at least, it's time to do it.

Comment: Not sure if it has a different name, but nothing seems to appear on my coursebook similar to "Little Fermat". Is this the only way to solve this kind of questions? @DietrichBurde

Comment: You may be able to spot the pattern yourself, by quickly finding the remainders modulo 5 of $7,7^2, 7^3,7^4,\ldots $.

Comment: Certainly you should know this, it is very basic. Have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: What do you mean with `% 5`?

Comment: '%' is a common way of writing 'modulo' (or more strictly 'remainder') in lots of programming languages.

Comment: Often $\%5$ is an *operation* which will "spit out" a number between $0$ and $4$. So $243\% 5 = 3$ says that $243\% 5$ *IS* the number $3$. $\mod 5$ on the other hand isn't an operation that gives an output but says something about how two numbers are related.  $243\equiv 3\pmod 5$ isn't a *number*; its a statment that $243$ and $3$ have the same remainder.  Now with $\mod 5$ then statement $243\equiv 68\equiv 3\pmod 5$ is true but $243\% 5 = 68$ is not.   But $243\%5= 68\%5$ is.  This can be annoying when trying to state "the remainder of the sum is the sum of the remainders".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you don't know Fermat's little theorem yet.  So I won't tell you to use it.

But $7^1\% 5 = 2$.

And $7^2\% 2=2*7\% 5=14\% 4 = 4$

And $7^3\% 3 = 4*7\%5 = 28\% 5 = 3$

and $7^4\%4 = 3*7\%5 = 12\% 5 = 1$ and hey we're back to one!.

$7^5\%4 = 1*7\%5=7\% 5 = 2$.  We're back where we started.

So we going to repeat and repeat in $4$ term cylce.

The eggponent is $12345678=12345676 + 2$ which goes through a bunch of four term cycles and two more.  So $7^{12345678}\% 5 = 7^2 \% = 4$.

.....

Oh.... I guess I'm assuming it is intuitively obvious that if $a\% 5 = m$ and $b\% 5= n$ then $ab \% 5 = mn\% 5$......

I'll leave that to you to convince yourself it is clear.

Knowing this three things:

1. $(a+b)\% N = [(a\%N)+(b\% N)]\%N$
2. $(a\times b)\%N = [(a\%N)\times (b\%N)]\% N$
3. Theres only $5$ possible remainders (including $0$) so eventually these powers will repeat.

You should be able to solve this on your own.

Comment: for this calculation $7^2\% 2=2*7\% 5=14\% 4 = 4$, how did $2$ come up and followed by $2 * 7$? Also for $7^3\% 4$ and $7^4\% 3$?

Comment: $7\%5 = 2$ so $7^2\%5 = 7*7\%5 = 7*2\%5=14\%4 =4$.  And $7^3\%=7^2*7\% 5 = 4*7\%5=28\%5 = 3$.   Also because $7\%5 = 2$ we can replace *all* the $7$s with $2$s.  $7^3 \%5= 2^3\%5=8\5 5 = 3$.

Comment: Sorry, not quite getting the $7^4\%5$ part.

Comment: $7^4\%5 =7*(7^3)\%5 = 7*(7*(7^2))\%5 = 7*(7*(7*7)))\%5= 7*(7*(7*2))\%5=7*(7*(14))\%5 = 7*(7*4)\%5 = 7*(28)\%=7*3\% = 21\% = 1$.  So $7^{12345678}\%5=7^{12345676}7^2\%5=(7^4)^{3086419}*7^2\%5= (7^4\%5)^{3086419}*7^2\%5=1^{3086419}*7^2\%5=1*7^2\%5=7^2\%5$.

Answer (score 0):

As $152615278636986567767\equiv 7\mod 10$, we also have  $152615278636986567767\equiv 7\equiv 2\mod 5$.

Now by *lil' Fermat*, as $2$ and $5$ are coprime, we have $2^4\equiv 1\mod 5$, so that
$$152615278636986567767^{12345678}\equiv 2^{12345678}\equiv 2^{12345678\bmod4}=2^2\mod 5.$$

Comment: THis is fine.  But the OP clearly hasn't learned Little Fermat yet (or even the notation of $7\equiv 2 \pmod 5$).

Comment: Litle Fermat anyway isn't a problem, as it's about the powers og $2$ modulo $5$, but if he/she doesn't know the notion of modular arithmetic…